# 'unicode' object does not support item assignment (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: xxx)

Tags: openstack

From the  [openstack keystone client management doc](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/admin/cli-manage-projects-users-and-roles.html):

I use `openstack user list` to check the users in openstack, but get the bellow errors:

> 'unicode' object does not support item assignment (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-ccf9d2b6-0801-45fd-9000-7feb3783eedc)

Why get this issue? its strange.

In the openstack cloud mariadb's keystone database, I `selected * from user`, get the bellow information:

<kbd>[image: image description]</kbd>

---

**EDIT**

In my openstack cloud host machine's `/var/log/keystone.log`:

```
......
2017-09-20 15:15:24.376 9503 INFO keystone.common.wsgi [req-53ed55d1-125f-4ee7-b548-39c8d4e9c062 - - - - -] GET http://controller:35357/v3/users
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi [req-53ed55d1-125f-4ee7-b548-39c8d4e9c062 - - - - -] 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/wsgi.py", line 228, in __call__
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     result = method(req, **params)
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/controller.py", line 235, in wrapper
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     return f(self, request, filters, **kwargs)
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/identity/controllers.py", line 231, in list_users
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     return UserV3.wrap_collection(request.context_dict, refs, hints=hints)
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/controller.py", line 499, in wrap_collection
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     cls.wrap_member(context, ref)
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/controller.py", line 468, in wrap_member
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     cls._add_self_referential_link(context, ref)
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/common/controller.py", line 464, in _add_self_referential_link
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi     ref['links']['self'] = cls.base_url(context) + '/' + ref['id']
2017-09-20 15:15:24.416 9503 ERROR keystone.common.wsgi TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I find the extra data format of several row is wrong .

See the user's extra column in the snapshot. the data is like bellow:

```
{"email": "xxxx@xx.com", "links":"http://103.x5.xx.1/user_resource/liaoss07"}
```

But should pay attention the `links` should not like that, so, I set the extra to `{}` which extra is like this abnormal.

my solution is :

```
UPDATE user SET extra='{}' WHERE id=xxx
```

and you can leave the email in the `{}` too.